# Xamarin.Forms.Color to hex value

Tags: c#, xamarin, colors, xamarin.forms, hex

I have a Xamarin.Forms.Color and I want to convert it to a 'hex value'.

So far, I haven't found a solution to my problem.

My code is as follows:

```
foreach (var cell in Grid.Children)
{
    var pixel = new Pixel
    {
        XAttribute = cell.X ,
        YAttribute = cell.Y ,
        // I want to convert the color to a hex value here
        Color = cell.BackgroundColor
    };
}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just a quick fix, the last line is wrong.

Alpha channel comes before the other values:

```
string hex = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", alpha, red, green, blue);
```

and this is best for an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static string GetHexString(this Xamarin.Forms.Color color)
    {
        var red = (int)(color.R * 255);
        var green = (int)(color.G * 255);
        var blue = (int)(color.B * 255);
        var alpha = (int)(color.A * 255);
        var hex = $"#{alpha:X2}{red:X2}{green:X2}{blue:X2}";

        return hex;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your post but this did not work for me, I was testing with #14808c output was totally not the same color. Thanks

Comment: @HusseinKhalil Remove the alpha and this will fix it

Answer (score 12):

```
var color = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Orange;
int red = (int) (color.R * 255);
int green = (int) (color.G * 255);
int blue = (int) (color.B * 255);
int alpha = (int)(color.A * 255);
string hex = String.Format("#{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}{3:X2}", red, green, blue, alpha);
```

Comment: Code Knox's answer is the correct syntax. `Alpha` channel should come first - https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Color/

Comment: @HusseinKhalil it might worked because your color doesn't use the alpha chanel otherwise it won't be the expected color because the format of hex is ARGB : #AARRGGBB and in the given code it is #RRGGBBAA

Answer (score 4):

a bit late but here is how I do that in Xamarin Forms (the Xamarin.Forms.Color class already exposes a FromHex(string) method.

```
public string ColorHexa { get; set; }
public Color Color
{
    get => Color.FromHex(ColorHexa);
    set => ColorHexa = value.ToHexString();
}
```

With this extension :

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static string ToHexString(this Color color, bool outputAlpha = true)
    {
        string DoubleToHex(double value)
        {
            return string.Format("{0:X2}", (int)(value * 255));
        }

        string hex = "#";
        if (outputAlpha) hex += DoubleToHex(color.A);
        return $"{hex}{DoubleToHex(color.R)}{DoubleToHex(color.G)}{DoubleToHex(color.B)}";
    }
}
```

Comment: `(int)value * 255` != `(int)(value * 255)`

Comment: This code needs to be corrected. As @foxanna mentions, the term (int)value * 255 rounds the given R/G/B double value to integer 0 or 1... which results in hex strings of #000000 or #FFFFFF.

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the hex color in the format `#{Alpha}{R}{G}{B}`.

For example `#FFFF0000` for Red.

```
color.ToHex();
```

Comment: @SurajKumar This answers the author question which was "I want to convert it to a 'hex value'." The line of code I suggest does exactly that.

Comment: It may be my mistake but in all the cases your answer should have a description as you can see in another answer.