# Not supported exception while creating table

Tags: database, sqlite, exception, colors, xamarin.forms

```
System.NotSupportedException: Don't know about Xamarin.Forms.Color
  at SQLite.Orm.SqlType (SQLite.TableMapping+Column p, System.Boolean storeDateTimeAsTicks)
```

I got this exception while creating a database in  xamarin forms. I have color property as column in my table, is this exception because of that or what causes this exception?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin.Forms Sqlite-net NotSupportedException on ManyToOne relationship "Don't know about <model>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668282/xamarin-forms-sqlite-net-notsupportedexception-on-manytoone-relationship-dont)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a Color field in Sqlite table. Actually only a limited [data types](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) are allowed in Sqlite database.
To resolve this issue you can first [convert the color object to a hex string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43532125/5941852) equivalent, and then save this string to Sqlite table.
And finally when you want to get the saved color, you can convert back this hex string to a Xamarin.Forms Color object by this line of code:

```
Color color = Color.FromHex(hexString);
```

Comment: yeah its correct, i figured it out just before you posted this, thanks @vahid